# OpenCV printing out an element of a matrix

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to print an element of a matrix which stores an image, but for some reason I get a debug error. The function abort() keeps calling. I have pasted the code bellow:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main(){
    Mat img = imread("D:/OwnResearch/photo2.jpg");
    std::cout << img.at<int>(1, 1, 1) << std::endl;
    return 0;

}
```

I was wondering if there is any way to get an ith, jth, kth element or the matrix img (type Mat)?

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use any type you want with Mat::at(), you must stick to the one it is bound to. if you imread() an image without any further flags, this type will be Vec3b (24bit bgr), *never* int. also, you have to check, if imread actually succeded before doing so:

```
Mat img = imread("D:/OwnResearch/photo2.jpg");
if ( ! img.empty() )
{
    std::cout << img.at<Vec3b>(1, 1) << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access any element as exampled below.

```
 img.at<uchar>(x , y)[channel]
```

using "uchar" should be better if you read from jpeg file.

more detailed: http://www.developerstation.org/2012/01/access-mat-in-c-using-opencv.html

Comment: I am not sure what channel stands for?

Comment: channel means red , green , blue value of pixel.